# What term means "covering a wall entirely"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The term "relief mural" describes a mural which uses a relief-technique. I need a term, preferably one used in fine arts, which places emphasis on the fact that the piece is a relief, but with the scale and properties of a mural, e.g. "(term) relief". Here is a sample sentence:

> The sculptor made the (term) relief.

I could not find any adjective form of "mural" and "wall-covering relief" sounds too unprofessional.

Is there an adjective or similar term used in fine arts which describes the property of covering a wall?

Comment: There's the term "wallpaper," which may not be what you want, but it _does_ apply sometimes (think about the "wallpaper" on your desktop, e.g.). It's also worth noting that "mural" can also serve as an [adjective](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mural).

Comment: Covering it with what? Plants, a coat of paint, wallpaper, a painting, shelves, furniture, ... ?

Comment: Tiling or tiled work, but don't usually refer to murals or tapestries.

Comment: Can you edit  your question to give a full sentence with a slot for the word you're trying to fill?

Answer (score 5):

If a wall is covered with something, it is "blanketed," which implies there are no blank(!) spaces between whatever blankets the wall.  This is particularly apt when in the fine arts the substance that blankets the wall is paint, as in a mural.

Comment: Good choice! Very apt for OP's need.

Comment: I find "blanket" to be an unusual choice since I've never seen a wall covered in blanket, but I have seen a wall covered in plaster.  Whether or not wall plaster should be compared to high art is a different matter.

Answer (score 3):

Muraled, plastered, coated, or even tiled would be a few words that would suggest your intended meaning.  As far as communicating that an entire wall was covered you might have to include context, as in;

> A tile coated wall.

or,

> a wall coated with tiles, such as a [Byzantine mosaic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic#Byzantine_mosaics).

Answer (score 1):

Consider

> - accoutre
> - adorn
> - bedeck
> - blazon
> - coat
> - drape
> - dress
> - emblazon
> - embroider
> - enrobe
> - enswathe
> - enwrap
> - festoon
> - garb
> - mantle
> - swathe